# Create Dialog Maxscript???

Tags: dialog, maxscript

Could someone tell me whats wrong here? I am bit of a newbie to max-script but its weird why this is not working

try(DestroyDialog Run)catch()

Rollout Run "TestCondition"  width: 200 height: 250

--  button btn_test "Test"   pos:[50,50] width: 75
--  spinner spn_check "Checked"    fieldwidth: 25

CreateDialog Run

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brackets around rollout items:

```
try (destroyDialog Run) catch()
rollout Run "TestCondition" width:200 height:250
(
    button btn_test "Test" pos:[50, 50] width:75
    spinner spn_check "Checked" fieldWidth:25
)
createDialog Run
```